# Macro that will copy only cells with data and paste in a different worksheet

Tags: macros, copy-paste

I need create a macro that will copy cells that go from A2 to O2 in the worksheet DL and continue for a varrying amount of rows. (Depends on the month). I need this pasted in the worksheet Efficiency in rows A2 to O2.

Because every time I create the report the number of rows of data changes I'm running into issues with creating an effective macro.

Also, some of the rows don't have information in every column, but I still want the blank cells to be coppied in this case. Basically if there is data in column A I want the rest of the row to column O to be copied as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of [those suggestions](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0058.html) help you out?

Also, I'm a bit confused of what are you referring to when you write "rows". A row has a number (1 to 1048576 in Office 2010 and up) and a column has a letter (A to XFD in Office 2010 and up). So what do you mean by "row A2 to O2"?

**EDIT:** Also, to copy from A to O every time, you simply set the range from A to O. For example `Range("A2:O10")` would include every cell from A2 to O10. Since you set the range with simple strings you can select the row numbers with the help of one of the suggestions in the link I gave you.